# iOS 4.2 How to Display a different image on orientation change?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, ios-4.2, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

iOS4.2 When my app launches I display an image that is visible until my webview loads.  After the webview loads that image is set to hidden.  How do I do the following:   If portrait, then display DefaultPortrait.png if Landscape the display DefaultLandscape.png?

if Device is Portrait then display

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default2.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];
```

OR

if Device is landscape then display

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480f, 320.0f);
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default2L.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];
```

Comment: Just try my method. Put in the viewDidRotateMethod in ur code. This function will be called whenever the device will be rotated..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to implement your code. Now here when the orientation will be changed from portrait implement the code u wanna display when the device is in landscape mode and vice versa. Hope it solves your problem.

```
    - (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {

        // your method for landscape..

    }
    if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {

        //your method for portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen to not do what I had originally intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this at the beginning to get your current orientation:

```
   UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

and then use this:

```
 if ((currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default2.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];

    }
   else if ((currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default2.png"]];
myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];
}
```

Comment: http://earthHappens.com/eHap.html  I put myviewController .h .m file on my server.  I get no error codes but my image does not change when the orientation does.  I'm stumped

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen to not do what I had originally intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display same image in both mode then first u declare a Boolean type variable in app delegate file and define in app delegate .m file. IF portrait mode the  variable true and when landscape then false. Now In

```
_(void)viewDidLoad{
              if (Boolean variable == TRUE ){
                                         //display portrait mode }
                 else 
                      //display landscape mode
```

}

Comment: 2 different images  Default2.png and Default2L.png

Comment: Display Default2.png when in portrait and display Default2L.png when in landscape.

Comment: earthHappens.com/eHap.html I put myviewController .h .m file on my server. I get no error codes but my image does not change when the orientation does. I'm stumped

Comment: in app delegate.h file u declare a boolean type variable and u check ur device can check orientation change or not

Comment: in appdelegate.h file u declare as Bool IsLandscape; in app delegate.m file u synthesize it. And in rotation function u define as   if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
      IsLandScape = False;
    }
    if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
         IsLandScape=TRUE;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen to not do what I had originally intended to do.